# Modal Render Inside Ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, cellrenderer

I have Create Custom select Component for Ag-grid which will show additional detail via click on the button when I press the button it will open Modal and show Additional information problem is that I'm using the same logic for my forms and Grid when I open additional information from form its properly show modal with Detail but when I press additional information from Grid it's showing modal under the same row here is my component definition.

I'm using ngb-modal

@Component({
selector: 'select-cell',
template:  `<my-dropdown #select (change)="valueChange()" [(ngModel)]="value"></my-dropdown>`,
// styleUrls: ['selectStyle.css']
})

export class GridDropDownComponent implements AgRendererComponent, AfterViewInit {
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
}